# Is there a top-down documentation for WordPress?

Tags: documentation

This may sound like a silly question, but is there any technical top-down documentation that explains how WordPress works?

There's a lot of "How to..." style documentation, i.e. explaining how to get a certain thing (install, write a theme,...) done, but I have trouble finding any documentation that provides the bigger picture, explaining how WordPress interacts with the web server, what major components/concepts exist, how they are organized in the install and how they work together to create the delivered web pages.

I guess, if I follow enough links on [Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins), [Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Themes), [Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Templates), ... I'll eventually get a (hopefully) fairly complete picture, but I'd much prefer starting with high level documentation and then drill down in areas that are immediately relevant to me.

Comment: A useful reference: https://gist.github.com/johnbillion/4fa3c4228a8bb53cc71d

Comment: Nice to see a great question, +1

Comment: See [Make.WordPress.com](https://make.wordpress.org/training/handbook/user-lessons/basic-wordpress-concepts/) and [WordPress Server Side and Client Side Understanding](http://wpshout.com/understanding-server-side-client-side-wordpress/)

Comment: @totels: Nice reference indeed.

Comment: @Shiva: thanks, those seem mostly user (as opposed to developer) focussed. There's certainly a bit of helpful overlap (particularly regarding explaining concepts), though.

Answer (score 5):

WordPress is very... utilitarian I suppose. People tend to use and know as much as they need to get things done. Curiously that tends to exclude the low level core load process.

It doesn't help the situation that (unlike modern frameworks) WordPress doesn't use a complete routing logic for everything. Front-end is governed by rewrite/permalinks, while back end is a spaghetti of different non-virtual endpoints.

The closest I had come to mapping it out myself is my [core load](http://www.rarst.net/wordpress/wordpress-core-load/) graphic.

But overall there are so many things going on, that summarizing it completely is rather futile. You just live and learn (if you choose to :).

Comment: Very nice graphic for the core load. Will keep it bookmarked. Alas that's really only a part of the documentation I was looking for.